# Return a value from a class with a static function

Tags: php

I have this simple thing:

```
class Pkg {

    const A = 10;
    const B = 100;
    const C = 1000;

    public static function limit($pkg){
        $args = func_get_args();
        $param =  $args[0];
        return self::$param;
    }

}
```

And i have this in outer controller:

```
 $ownerPkg = 'A';
 dd(Pkg::limit($ownerPkg));
```

How do i get the value of A from my Pkg class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function to do this:

```
return constant("self::$param");
```